# Limit table to 15 rows and click on "Load more" to load more 15 rows in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code that brings all the analysis documents of a client, but if the client has 1000 lines he loads the 1000 in one page. I wanted to divide it into numbers of 20 lines at a time.

How do I delimit the first view showing only 20 lines  and after clicking "load more" load 20 more and so on until all lines are loaded?

```
  const [downloading, setDownloading] = useState(false);
  const [downloadID, setDownloadID] = useState(0);

  return items.length === 0 ? null : (
    <div className="table-responsive">
      <table className="table">
        <tbody>
          {items.map((a) => {
            const sequential = `${a.sequential}`.padStart(7, "0");

            return (
              <tr key={a.id}>
                <th scope="row">
                  <h6 className="list-title">ID da análise</h6>
                  {a.customerCode}-{sequential}
                </th>
                <th>
                  <h6 className="list-title">Nome do equipamento</h6>
                  {a.machine.equipmentName}
                </th>
                <th>
                  <h6 className="list-title">Setor localizado</h6>
                  <div>{a.machine.sectorName}</div>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <h6 className="list-title">Data de criação</h6>
                  {toLocaleDateTime(a.createdAt)}
                </th>
                <th className="no-wrap no-width">
                  <h6 className="list-title">Ações</h6>
                  <Button
                    title="Relatório da Análise"
                    id="relatorioPdf"
                    icon="fas fa-file-pdf"
                    customClassName="btn-primary btn-sm mb-0 mt-0"
                    disabled={downloading}
                    loading={downloading && a.id === downloadID}
                    onClick={() =>
                      download(
                        a.id,
                        `${a.customerCode}-${sequential}`,
                        global.modal,
                        setDownloading,
                        setDownloadID
                      )
                    }
                  />
                  <UncontrolledTooltip
                    placement="bottom"
                    target="relatorioPdf"
                  >
                    Baixar Relatório em PDF
                  </UncontrolledTooltip>
                </th>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: https://upmostly.com/tutorials/build-an-infinite-scroll-component-in-react-using-react-hooks. - Check this

Comment: Thanks mate! I Will check!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is split the items array into to multiples arrays with 20 items max, for that you can use `chunk` lodash helper (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk),as follows:

```
lodash.chunk(items, 20)
```

This helper will return and array of arrays, then you need to create a separate array to display the elements and keep moving the element from one array to other every time you click "Load more" button.

Comment: Thanks Selvio! I will try!